# Pygame, 'Class' Object has no attribute rect

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple game with python and pygame, and I'm trying to populate the screen with enemies by using a for loop. I have what looks to me like identical code in the other parts of my game, but for whatever reason I'm getting the error

> AttributeError: 'Enemy object has no attribute 'rect'

I changed the values for `enemy.rect.x` and `enemy.rect.y` to 500 and 500 just to see if it was the variable I was using that was causing the error but it wasn't.

Here's the pastebin for the full code... http://pastebin.com/ZJ2u9w7t

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Projects portfolio\PythonStuff\ShipTest.PY", line 119, in <module>
main()

File "D:\Projects portfolio\PythonStuff\ShipTest.PY", line 109, in main
enemy.rect.x = 500
AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'rect'
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

Comment: Quick tip: You should try to clean up your code a bit first and actually put it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I trying doing the code block in the post but wasn't formatting everything correctly, never actually used paste bin either but thought that it showing line numbers would be really helpful with the trace back.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 73:

`def __init_(self):`

You might prefer:

`def __init__(self):`

Given your typo, your Enemy class does not have a constructor when you instantiate it, however, you do have a useless method __init_. And hence you get an `AttributeError` when you do `.rect.x`.

EDIT: semi-useless, you still get some expected behaviour because you call `super().__init__()` within `__init_`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you forgot an underscore.

In line 73 of your code you accidentally wrote this:

```
def __init_(self):
```

You are missing an underscore (the last one). You have two on the left side and one on the right side. To complete the initialization correctly, you need to add an underscore like so:

```
def __init__(self):
```

This will then allow the `Enemy` class to have a rect due to that you have `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` anyways. The missing underscore will always raise an `Attribute Error` if it is the only error/first error in your code.

Comment: Omg I wanna shoot myself right now. I'm surprised that didn't throw an error itself. Just started learning a few weeks ago. Novice mistake I guess. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: You should accept one answer, and maybe upvote the one you don't select as the answer given we both responded within a few minutes of each other.

Comment: Totally agreed with you. Nice answer by the way.